# How to use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT with an OR condition

Tags: c++, enable-if

For example I have

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
     boost::has_range_iterator<T>::value,
);
```

but I have other types that are range like that I can detect with

is_foo_type::value

How do I combine the two as a disjunction. ie in psuedocode

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
     std::or<
       boost::has_range_iterator<T>::value,
       is_foo_type<T>::value
     >::value
);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `A::value || B::value`?

Comment: Doh! The obvious. I was looking for something way too complex :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *C++17* you could use a type trait [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction):

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
     std::disjunction_v<
       boost::has_range_iterator<T>::value,
       is_foo_type<T>::value
     >
);
```

Before *C++17* you have to use `||`, as @StoryTeller has mentioned:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::has_range_iterator<T>::value || is_foo_type<T>::value);
```